# Font size problems with external plugin?

Tags: css

I downloaded a slider plugin after implemeting my web app.  Now the app's font size has been changed against my will. Its CSS code:

```
  .content h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
```

Comment: What is the question here? If you want to prevent it- did you try changing the css?

Comment: Font size is very small then showing in demo.